# one-to-many and on delete cascade table constraint

Tags: hibernate, jpa, cascade

I have a bi-directional one-to-many between Account and Transaction:

```
@Entity

public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID")
    private Account account;
    ...
}
```

The foreign key has ON DELETE CASCADE constraint defined:

```
alter table transaction
    add constraint FK6
        foreign key (account_id)
            references account(id) on delete cascade;
```

But then, when deleting an 'account' record why does hibernate delete related 'transaction' records one by one:

```
acidTest(entityManager -> {
    Account _account = entityManager.find(Account.class, pk);
    assertThat(_account.getTransactions().size(), is(2));
});

acidTest(entityManager -> {
    Account account = entityManager.find(Account.class, 1L);
    entityManager.remove(account);
});
```

Log:

```
09:17:56.216 [main] DEBUG c.l.hibernate.JPATxBoundedTest - [TX: begin -->
Hibernate: 
    select
        account0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        ...
    from
        account account0_ 
    where
        account0_.id=?
09:17:56.223 [main] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [5]
Hibernate: 
    select
        transactio0_.account_id as account_4_14_0_,
        transactio0_.id as id1_14_0_,
        ... 
    from
        transaction transactio0_ 
    where
        transactio0_.account_id=?
09:17:56.230 [main] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [5]
Hibernate: 
    delete from transaction where id=?
09:17:56.241 [main] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [14]
Hibernate: 
    delete from transaction where id=?
09:17:56.245 [main] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [16]
Hibernate: 
    delete from account where id=?
09:17:56.249 [main] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [5]
09:17:56.260 [main] DEBUG c.l.hibernate.JPATxBoundedTest - <-- end: TX]
```

I expected hibernate to skip deleting 'transaction' as I did not specify CascadeType.REMOVE on the account -> transactions relationship. What gives?

(Adding CascadeType.REMOVE also triggered the same set of SQLs)

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable hibernate specific @OnDelete on the relation

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete(
action = org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
```

2. @OnDelete was still required even though hibernate is not managing my DDL:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

3. If you are using MySQL (I do!), ensure your storage engine is InnoDB, which supports ON DELETE CASCADE on foreign keys.